# Reading a binary file via fread()

Tags: c

How can i read it back so that I can see the contents in my console itself?
I used this way:

```
n = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);
printf("0x%x", buffer);
```

Here I am getting only 1 byte output, but the file contains 72 bytes.

Comment: In case you didn't see it, the "output" your currently getting is the address at `buffer` as an `int` in hex format, and has *nothing* to do with the content of the file you just read. See the documentation of [**`printf()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and what the format string representations expect. Then crack open your text/tutorial and learn about *control loops*. (you're going to need one).

Comment: What is `buffer`? An unsigned char? An array? A struct?

Comment: The second and third parameters of `fread` might be wrong. checkout [fread explained](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yves Daoust pointed out, %x formatter expects a single byte. Looping through the values will print all of them in hex.

```
n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("0x%x ", buffer[i]);
}
```

**Side note about fread:**

The second parameter to `fread` is size of each member you want to read whereas the third parameter holds total length of data you want to read (man page: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/) Although it may not have a visible impact in this case, in your code sample the two arguments seems to have been swapped.

Answer (score 0):

The %x format descriptor expects a single value, it does not handle arrays. You need to printf the 72 bytes one by one in a loop.

Comment: By the way, there is no way that the printf function could "guess" the value of n.